# Jacobi identity is satisfied in the non abelian exterior square group (for abelian Schur multiplier of a group).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, tensor-products, tensors

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Can we say that the Jacobi identity is satisfied in this group $G\wedge G$? As we can see that, $$\forall ~a,b,c \in G~~[[a,b],^bc][[b,c],^ca][[c,a],^ab]=e.$$ Can we say that for abelian groups $$((a\wedge b)\wedge c)((b\wedge c)\wedge a)((c\wedge a)\wedge b)=e$$

Where the non-abelian exterior square $G\wedge G$ of a group $G$ is a group generated by the elements of the set $\lbrace a\wedge b:~a,b \in G\rbrace$ satisfying the conditions:

(1) $a\wedge a=1$

(2) $(a\wedge b)(b\wedge a)=1$

(3) $ab\wedge c=(^ab\wedge ^ac )(a\wedge c)$

(4) $a\wedge bc=(a \wedge b)(^ba \wedge ^bc)$

for all $a,b,c \in G$. For abelian groups, this non-abelian exterior square becomes an alternating bilinear map.

Comment: Jacobi identity is for Lie algebras (not groups), right?

Comment: I am clarifying my question again.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sir, please watch the question again.

Comment: @PriyaPandey Can you give the previous information regarding this? Why are you asking this question? Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @MANI its just my intention.

Comment: You need to say what $^{b}a$ means. I suspect it means $bab^{-1}$, but in that case $^{b}a = a$, because the group is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no, it need not be true. For example, consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Then its non-abelian exterior square is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$. But you can check it by some computation that the Jacobi identity is not satisfied here. 
For reference, you may go through the link provided below

https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793557118500845

Comment: Can you tell me how may I get this research article freely? It is not showing free there. Please if possible, then do the calculation as you said. It will be better for me. Thanks

Comment: @PriyaPandey Sorry, I did my best, now it is your job to verify the rest things.

Comment: It is ok. never mind