# Is the exterior square distributive over direct product of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, tensors

My question is that,

> If $G, H, K, L$ are four groups. Can we say that
>
> $$(G\times H)\wedge (K \times L)\simeq (G\wedge K)\times (H \wedge L)?$$
>
> Or is there any other such relationship between them?

Here the non-abelian exterior square $G\wedge G$ of group $G$ is a group generated by the elements of the set $\lbrace a\wedge b:~a,b \in G\rbrace$ satisfying the conditions:

(1) $a\wedge a=1$

(2) $(a\wedge b)(b\wedge a)=1$

(3) $ab\wedge c=(^ab\wedge ^ac )(a\wedge c)$

(4) $a\wedge bc=(a \wedge b)(^ba \wedge ^bc)$

Comment: You define the nonabelian exterior square of a single group, but you ask us to apply the operation to two groups. What is the definition of this operation?

Answer (score 1):

I think, no this can not be possible. Otherwise, the answer given here [Jacobi identity is satisfied in the non abelian exterior square group (for abelian Schur multiplier of a group).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370509/jacobi-identity-is-satisfied-in-the-non-abelian-exterior-square-group-for-abelian).
will be discarded.